# Orange Geo Map does not show background map

Tags: orange

We are running Orange with our students and most of them are having problems with running the Geo Map widget. It does not show any background map. In the bottom an error message is displayed: `"Cannot fetch map from the Internet. Displaying only cached parts."`

I have found this Github page, but it does not explain how to update or add any JSON files that might be missing:
https://github.com/biolab/orange3-geo/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

What do we have to do to get the background maps to appear again in the Geo Map widget?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the Geo Map widget has been solved in a new release of Orange3. The Geo Map widget now works correctly again in **Orange3 version 3.23.1 and Geo Add-on version 0.26**. Great!